# Writing Unit Tests for sqflite for Flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing

My team and I have been writing unit tests for our Flutter App. We've used mockito to write unit tests for our providers. Now we're trying to write unit tests for database calls. How can we test our database calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you need. Using the `sqflite_ffi` package to create your database.

```
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

Future main() async {
  late Database database;
  // Setup sqflite_common_ffi for flutter test
  setUpAll(() {
    // Initialize FFI
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    // Change the default factory for unit testing calls for SQFlite
    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    database = Database();
  });

  tearDownAll(() {
    // Maybe delete the database here
  });
  
  // Tests here
  test('Example test'(){
    //Do your database calls here, query, delete, etc
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To clarify on the `tests here` section we can write our regular db query?  Also, where do we initialize the database?

Comment: ah yes the `test('Tests here',(){});` Let me edit it

Comment: Adding this reference here - https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/testing.md